# how to construct following query (left-right join and multiple update) in zend framework?

Tags: mysql, zend-framework

table1(id, field1, field2, field3), table2(id, table1_id, field1, field2, field3), and the query goes like this

```
select table1.*, table2.field2 as newfield from tabel1 
left join on table2 on table1.id = table2.table1_id;
```

I tried following code on Model

```
$select  = $this->select('table1.*', 'table2.field1')
->from('table1')
->joinLeft('table1', '`table2`.`table1.id` = `table1.id`.`table2.table1_id`')
->setIntegrityCheck(false);
```

but got result that i would get from inner join. Please Confirm me.

and I also would like to know how  to construct following query in Model

```
update table1 set field1 = 'somevalue' where id > someinteger.
```

regards

Comment: You can debug your queries like this: die((string)$select);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the select query:

```
// select(false) because you need to declare an identifier for table 1
// 't1' => $this->_name is better if this function is in the DbTable model
// setIntegrityCheck(false) because you need to join tables - you did this correctly
// joinLeft() arguments: array(table2id => table2_name),
//   'table2id.field = table1id.field', array(table2id.field as newfieldname)

$select = $this->select(false)
               ->from(array('t1' => 'table1'))
               ->setIntegrityCheck(false)
               ->joinLeft(
                   array('t2' => 'table2'),
                   't2.table1_id = t1.id',
                   array('t2.field2 as newfield')
               );
```

For the update query (within the DbTable model):

```
$data = array('field1' => 'somevalue');
$where = 'id > someinteger';
$this->update($data, $where);
```

***EDIT:*** Update and Increment Field in Multiple Rows

In SQL, you would do something such as the following:

```
UPDATE table_name SET field_name = field_name + x WHERE field_name < 5
```

Thus, using the code I listed above for update, you would do the following in ZF:

```
$this->update( array('field_name' => 'field_name + x') , 'field_name < 5' );
```

where of course x is the value by which you wish to increment everything.

Comment: Ankit if i have to increment the field1 value by 2 (i mean they all have different values and all incremented by two) then will it work ?

Comment: I've edited my post above to answer the question with CODE tags.

Comment: thnak you ankit. and sorry for responding late.